# PHP XML Parsing: Amazon Product API Response

Tags: php, xml

**I am trying to do following:** using core PHP (without any framework or plugin) & AMAZON API

1. generate a signed URL
2. query amazon for certain keyword using the signed url
3. Get the response in XML format
4. Parse the XML & display in a tabular format in HTML

   So far I have been able to complete upto step 3, but unable to complete step 4 of parsing the XML & displaying the data.

**Attachments:**

- [Screenshot of the XML file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YGvhf.png) - I want to display the items marked with a red arrow. These items appear 10 times in the XML file
- [Google drive link to actual XML file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BwIs2C21XzK_bnNmakVhd1FNVk0)

**Code sample:**

```
 $file = file_get_contents($request_url);
    $xml = simplexml_load_string($file);
    print_r($xml);
```

**Output:** I am pasting the first 2 of 10 array elements that I am getting from above print_r;

> ( [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [ASIN] => 8184954018 [DetailPageURL] => amazon.in/Chanakyas-Secrets-Leadership-Sivanandhan-Radhakrishnan/dp/8184954018?SubscriptionId=AKIAJ5B7EPH4TJ6YEUUQ&tag=30061200-21&linkCode=xm2&camp=2025&creative=165953&creativeASIN=8184954018 [ItemLinks] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [ItemLink] => Array ( [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [Description] => Add To Wishlist [URL] => amazon.in/gp/registry/wishlist/add-item.html?asin.0=8184954018&SubscriptionId=AKIAJ5B7EPH4TJ6YEUUQ&tag=30061200-21&linkCode=xm2&camp=2025&creative=165953&creativeASIN=8184954018 ) [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [Description] => Tell A Friend [URL] => amazon.in/gp/pdp/taf/8184954018?SubscriptionId=AKIAJ5B7EPH4TJ6YEUUQ&tag=30061200-21&linkCode=xm2&camp=2025&creative=165953&creativeASIN=8184954018 ) [2] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [Description] => All Customer Reviews [URL] => amazon.in/review/product/8184954018?SubscriptionId=AKIAJ5B7EPH4TJ6YEUUQ&tag=30061200-21&linkCode=xm2&camp=2025&creative=165953&creativeASIN=8184954018 ) [3] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [Description] => All Offers [URL] => amazon.in/gp/offer-listing/8184954018?SubscriptionId=AKIAJ5B7EPH4TJ6YEUUQ&tag=30061200-21&linkCode=xm2&camp=2025&creative=165953&creativeASIN=8184954018 ) ) ) [ItemAttributes] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [Author] => D. Sivanandhan Radhakrishnan Pillai [Manufacturer] => Jaico Publishing House [ProductGroup] => Book [Title] => Chanakya's 7 Secrets of Leadership )
>
> [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [ASIN] => B00EA0Q3PW [DetailPageURL] => amazon.in/Improve-Your-Leadership-Management-Skills-ebook/dp/B00EA0Q3PW?SubscriptionId=AKIAJ5B7EPH4TJ6YEUUQ&tag=30061200-21&linkCode=xm2&camp=2025&creative=165953&creativeASIN=B00EA0Q3PW [ItemLinks] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [ItemLink] => Array ( [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [Description] => Add To Wishlist [URL] => amazon.in/gp/registry/wishlist/add-item.html?asin.0=B00EA0Q3PW&SubscriptionId=AKIAJ5B7EPH4TJ6YEUUQ&tag=30061200-21&linkCode=xm2&camp=2025&creative=165953&creativeASIN=B00EA0Q3PW ) [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [Description] => Tell A Friend [URL] => amazon.in/gp/pdp/taf/B00EA0Q3PW?SubscriptionId=AKIAJ5B7EPH4TJ6YEUUQ&tag=30061200-21&linkCode=xm2&camp=2025&creative=165953&creativeASIN=B00EA0Q3PW ) [2] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [Description] => All Customer Reviews [URL] => www.amazon.in/review/product/B00EA0Q3PW?SubscriptionId=AKIAJ5B7EPH4TJ6YEUUQ&tag=30061200-21&linkCode=xm2&camp=2025&creative=165953&creativeASIN=B00EA0Q3PW ) [3] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [Description] => All Offers [URL] => amazon.in/gp/offer-listing/B00EA0Q3PW?SubscriptionId=AKIAJ5B7EPH4TJ6YEUUQ&tag=30061200-21&linkCode=xm2&camp=2025&creative=165953&creativeASIN=B00EA0Q3PW ) ) ) [ItemAttributes] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [Author] => Meir Liraz [Manufacturer] => Liraz Publishing [ProductGroup] => eBooks [Title] => How to Improve Your Leadership and Management Skills - Effective Strategies for Business Managers )

**What help I require:** Out of above two array elements what PHP code will get me the output table with following columns

- ASIN
- Title
- Author
- Details URL
- Customer Review URL

Comment: use echo "<pre>" before print_r .. then you can easily read

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basis of what you want can be processed easily by using DOMDocument rather than with SimpleXML.  The default namespace (xmlns definition in the ItemSearchResponse element) makes SimpleXML not so simple.

But as a start, the following code should help...

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$file = file_get_contents("t1.xml");
$xml = new DOMDocument();
$xml->loadXML($file);
$items = $xml->getElementsByTagName("Items")[0];
foreach ( $items->getElementsByTagName("Item") as $item )    {
    echo "ASIN:".$item->getElementsByTagName("ASIN")[0]->nodeValue.PHP_EOL;
    echo "Author:".$item->getElementsByTagName("Author")[0]->nodeValue.PHP_EOL;
}
```

All this does is to first extract the `<items>` element and the uses a loop to fetch each `<item>` element in that.  In the loop you can see that it's extracting individual elements data by using the appropriate name.

As each call to `getElementsByTagName` returns an array of elements, thats why you have to say use just the first one (assuming this is correct, if not you can `foreach` over them).

Comment: Glad to help, can you mark the answer as correct (when you can) as it shows the problem is solved.  Thanks